# how to write a function that smooths a given array

Tags: c

I am writing a function which smooths the given n element array with signature `void smoothData(int n, double data[])` according to the `1:2:1` filter given below. I should not generate entire new array and copy it back to original array.

```
si=(d(i−1)+2*di+d(i+1))/4
```

First and last element of smoothed array should be got from following rule instead of using `si`

```
s0=(3*d0+d1)/4

s(n−1)=(d(n−2)+3*d(n−1))/4
```

where `si` is the `i-th` element in smoothed array, `d` is the input array.
`d(n-1)` is the `(n-1)th` element of original array etc.

I got output of `1.250, 2.250, 4.000, 4.000`. The third element is wrong, which should be `3.500`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJqb.png

```
#include <stdio.h>

void smoothData(int n, double data[])
{

    double s0 = (data[0] * 3 + data[1]) / 4.0;
    double sLast = (data[n-2] + data[n-1] * 3) / 4.0;
    double si = 0.0;
    double di = data[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<=n-4; i++) {  
        si = (di + 2 * data[i+1] + data[i+2])/4.0;
        di = data[i+1];
        data[i+1] = si;            
    }
    data[0] = s0;
    data[n-1] = sLast;    
}

int main()
{

    double data[] = {1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0};
    smoothData(4, data);
    printf("Smoothed data: %.3lf", data[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        printf(", %.3lf", data[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: `2di`? do you mean `2 * di`? (same for `3d`?) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the code must be as text in the question itself

Comment: p21 Please [edit] your question to incorporate the hints given in above comments, to get it out of "on hold". I can't write my answer before.

Comment: @David -it should be 2 * di and same for 3d as it is mathematical relation, i thought i don't need to mention it.

Comment: I figured it was, but we always ask. People do some pretty screwy thing in questions....

Comment: I tried to edit question but couldn't do it perfectly, sorry i am new to this site,

Comment: There now is a MCVE, good work. I vote to reopen and itch to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 0; i<=n-4; i++)`

This means that if `n` is 4, the loop will only get executed once, because `0 <= 0` is true. So the loop will write to item `data[i+1] = si;` which is item 1. Then stop.

Later you write to `data[0] = s0;` which is item 0 and `data[n-1] = sLast;` which is item 3. But nowhere do you write to item 2, so it will remain untouched.

Comment: i changed it to -  for (int i = 0; i<=n-2; i++), it worked, Do i need to change i<=n-2 to < n-2, as in the expression si = (di + 2 * data[i+1] + data[i+2])/4.0; it is accessing data[n] which is out of the array, but i got correct answer without changing i<=n-2 to i<n-2